# Trying to insert text from file to 2D array. Java. Text is different formats

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

So I have a text file containing ints, doubles, strings that I need to read into a 2D array. there Array should have 6 columns but the rows are not known until you read the entire file. I'm guessing it is some 700 rows This is what I have so far. If I eliminate the array it prints fine but with the array I keep getting errors.
I have searched many questions like this but they usually only work with ints/doubles. Also please don't recommend arrayList as that has not been taught in our course.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TitanicApp {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
       String[][] array=null;
        int i=0, j=0;
        String fileLine;
        String s;
        Scanner scannerIn=null;
        BufferedReader inputStream=null;
        try{
            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("titanic.txt"));
            scannerIn = new Scanner(inputStream);

            while ((fileLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null){
                for (j=0;j<6;j++){

                    array [i][j]=scannerIn.next();
                    System.out.println(array[i][j]);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Sample text in file :**

```
1   1   Allen, Miss. Elisabeth Walton   female  29  211.3375
1   1   Allison, Master. Hudson Trevor  male    0.9167  151.5500
```

**And the output should be :**

```
[ [1,   1,  Allen, Miss. Elisabeth Walton,  female, 29, 211.3375]
  [1,   1,  Allison, Master. Hudson Trevor, male,   0.9167, 151.5500]
]
```

I have a txt file containing the above info (and more lines) and I need to put it into a 2D array. I had to remove more than half of it since there was a limit.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Also, you are going to get an NullPointer Exception as "array" is null.

Comment: Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: Do something like : String[][] array = new String[6][];

Comment: Now I'm getting java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.lang.String[][]

Comment: There is no clear way actually using array. You can look at the source code of ArrayList to get the idea how you can do it. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.ensureCapacity%28int%29

Comment: So I finally managed to get it into a one dimensional array using readline but I need the info in the array to be separated. What i mean is the line contains info like:1 1 Allen, Miss. Elisabeth Walton female 29 211.3375. which is now stored altogether but i need to seperate it to do calculations. Any idea on that?

Comment: Ok, I have given a sample example, which you can use as reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to do it using array only. You can consider below example as reference -

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TitanicApp {

    int size = 10;
    int colCount = 6;
    String[][] array = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TitanicApp app = new TitanicApp();
        app.startExec();
    }

    public void startExec() {

        array = new String[size][colCount];
        String fileLine;
        int i=0;

        try 
        {
            BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/titanic.txt"));
            while ((fileLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                addTo2DArray(fileLine.split("\\t"), ++i);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Now you have the desired array : array;
    }

    public void addTo2DArray(String[] tmpArray, int minCapacity) {
        if((minCapacity > size)) {
            size = (size * 3)/2 + 1;
            String[][] newArray = new String[size][colCount];
            for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++) {
                    newArray[i][j]=array[i][j];
                }
            }
            array = newArray;
        }
        array[minCapacity-1] = tmpArray;
    }
}
```

**Another Solution :**

```
String content = new Scanner(new File("/titanic.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
String[] rows = content.split("\n");
String[][] finalArray = new String[rows.length][];
for(int i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
{
    finalArray[i] = rows[i].split("\\t");
}
//Your desired array is : finalArray;
```

Comment: I am so lost in your code. Maybe my start isn't good. Is there another way to convert rows of info like my sample to a 2D array?

Comment: Post your txt file and post the final array you want.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I don't see an attach option here. I tried to copy some of the text but is isn't clear.It is in my original post. The info i need to store is lines like: 3 0 Zimmerman, Mr. Leo male  29 7.8750

Comment: I have updated your question. See if it's correct or not. Also how the six fields are separated, TAB?

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, you are incrementing both array locations, (i and j), at the same time. If you want the input to go in sequential order in the array increment j until array.size and then increment i. An example would be a nested for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < array.size; j++){
        array[i][j] = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(array[i][j]);
    }
}
```

or in your case, stop incrementing the values until i and j get to 6 instead of array.size

Comment: That is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need declare a size for your String[][], otherwise you will get a NullPointerException. ArrayLists are the only way to dynamically generate the list as you move on as far as my knowledge goes.

Comment: yes this is what I'm getting. I don't know the size. What can I do?

Comment: Just read the number of lines and then set the array size then reset the pointer, but I think you need to mark the pointer first. Or you could just reassign the inputStream and scannerIn variables to new again. 

Have a look at read and reset methods in BufferedReader. I don't know them myself too well.

Please upvote my post